# Transfer Database to new location raised MySQL Error function already exists

Tags: drupal, database, error, mysql

I follow the instructions here https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+the+database+using+phpMyAdmin

I want to import the so called Old_without_five_tables.sql with phpmyadmin in the civicrm database but I get the following error:

SQL query:

```
- Datenbank: `civicrm`
--

DELIMITER $$
--
-- Funktionen
--
CREATE DEFINER=`civicrm`@`localhost` 
FUNCTION `civicrm_strip_non_numeric`(input VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8
   NO SQL
   DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE output   VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE iterator INT          DEFAULT 1;
  WHILE iterator < (LENGTH(input) + 1) DO
    IF SUBSTRING(input, iterator, 1) IN ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9') THEN
      SET output = CONCAT(output, SUBSTRING(input, iterator, 1));
    END IF;
    SET iterator = iterator + 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN output;
END$$
```

MySQL said:

> #1304 - FUNCTION civicrm_strip_non_numeric already exists

I am using:
civicrm 4.7.3
drupal 7.26

thanks so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error suggests that you did run the import for the second time. The function cannot be created because it is already there. You can remove it with

```
DROP FUNCTION `civicrm_strip_non_numeric`
```

An alternative is to use the checkbox in *phpmyadmin* that is labeled *add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION*

(To be honest: I am not a phpmyadmin user, I got this suggestion from [What does the “Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION” checkbox do in phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760460/what-does-the-add-drop-table-view-procedure-function-checkbox-do-in-php) ).

Comment: Thanks this worked out and i can see all contacts. Just a short remark in the linked explaination (in my question) you should create a constraint.sql, i just skipped this step and it worked...